# Enable/Disbale cells of dropdown list in excel

Tags: excel, vba, dropdown

I have created a simple dropdown list. It looks something like this.

[image]

Here user is allowed to have multiple selection.

I want if user has selected options other than Not Applicable, then it should **disable Not Applicable** cell and **enable other cities** to select. But if user first **selects Not Applicable** then **other city option should be disable**. Also clicking on same cell will enable and disable the cell.

For E.g. First user decides not to select any country so he clicks on Not Applicable option and automatically "New York, Berlin, Mumbai, Munich" options gets disable. But later if user decides to select City option and if he again clicks on Not Applicable then it should get disable and other countries should get enable.

Also I have associated values to the cities and I am printing values.

[image]

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(Sheet2!A2:A6;Sheet1!A2))*Sheet2!B2:B6))
```

I have used follwoing multiple selection and removal code from the internet.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim xRng As Range
    Dim xValue1 As String
    Dim xValue2 As String
    If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    On Error Resume Next
    Set xRng = Me.Range("A2")
    If xRng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    If Not Application.Intersect(Target, xRng) Is Nothing Then
        xValue2 = Target.Value
        Application.Undo
        xValue1 = Target.Value
        Target.Value = xValue2
        If xValue1 <> "" Then
            If xValue2 <> "" Then
                If InStr(1, xValue1, xValue2 & ",") > 0 Then
                    xValue1 = Replace(xValue1, xValue2 & ", ", "") ' If it's in the middle with comma
                    Target.Value = xValue1
                    GoTo jumpOut
                End If
                If InStr(1, xValue1, ", " & xValue2) > 0 Then
                    xValue1 = Replace(xValue1, ", " & xValue2, "") ' If it's at the end with a comma in front of it
                    Target.Value = xValue1
                    GoTo jumpOut
                End If
                If xValue1 = xValue2 Then        ' If it is the only item in string
                    xValue1 = ""
                    Target.Value = xValue1
                    GoTo jumpOut
                End If
                Target.Value = xValue1 & ", " & xValue2
            End If
jumpOut:
        End If
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: What you need: `Worksheet_Change` event handler with `Target.Address`. When there is a change in the target cell then you run the code. What you want to do is use `Range.Validation.Modify` OR `Range.Validation.Delete` then `Range.Validation.Add`. Create named ranges of your default states and alternate between them per selection. You will also need to somehow reset your original lists so the user has flexibility to select an option again.

Comment: You can do this without VBA!!!

Comment: To get things straight: you want to prevent the user to be able to *select* certain cells based on what option was chosen from the dropdown list, correct?

Comment: @TimStack yes. When user selects N/A, all other cells will get disabled and if he chooses any city then N/A will get disabled

Answer (score 0):

Try the following (place it in the module from the sheet with the dropdown list):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim searchNA As Range
Dim LRow As Long

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A2")) Is Nothing Then
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
        LRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        Set searchNA = .Range("A2:A" & LRow).Find(Target.Value, lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=True)
        If Target.Value = "Not Applicable" Then
            .Range("A2:A" & LRow).Locked = True
            searchNA.Locked = False
        Else
            .Range("A2:A" & LRow).Locked = False
            searchNA.Locked = True
        End If
    End With
End If
End Sub
```

I have assumed the validation list is in `Worksheet("Sheet1")` and the small table with cities is in `"Sheet2"`